# VB.Net - Error in SQLDataReader and "Conversion from type 'DBNULL' to type 'Date' is not valid

Tags: sql, asp.net, .net, vb.net, sqldatareader

I'm new to VB.Net, and have to do a "crash get 'er done" project using VB.Net.  I've gotten a ways into it (in just 4 days), but am running into a serious issue at this point.

The SQL server database has a few date columns in it, and some are NULL.  I'm trying to build up a gridcontrol, and have a custom class to handle the data for each "row".

I have a SQLDataReader set up:

```
Using sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

The error is tripping on:

```
' this is an abbreviated statement of the original - many more values being passed
appsList.Add(New PromiseAppClass(sdr("PrimID"), sdr("lastname"),
     sdr("firstname"), sdr("middleinitial"), sdr("othernames"), 
     sdr("ssn"), sdr("date1"), sdr("date2")))
```

date1 and date2 are NULL in the DB, so the reader is failing attempting to convert to make the call to create the object (I'm assuming - VB isn't too explicit - to me - in detailing just WHERE the problem is here).  Both of those two items are set in the PromiseAppClass as Dates, with the normal getters/setters.

How to resolve?  Is there a method to code the particular variable in the class so that it can be tested/set there?  Or a method to convert a NULL date in the above statement into something acceptable?  I don't want to use a string, and not so sure I won't run into the same kind of problem, but now it can't convert NULL to string.

Comment: Check for null like this sdr("date1") != null ?sdr("date1") : ""

Comment: If this is an exact duplicate of an existing question - can you please pass a reference to it?  I've been searching here (and elsewhere) for 3 hours, and have NOT seen an "exact" duplicate.  The general question may be similar - the situation I've run into isn't necessarily the same - to me.  Until 4 days ago, I didn't work with VB, or even VS (at least not for nearly 20 years) - so if I'm missing something here - I apologize.  I've got an extreme time schedule for something that I'm trying to decipher as fast as I can.

Comment: `sdr.IsDBNull(index)`  will tell you if the column at that index is DbNull or not.  If it is, you need to decide what to pass instead.  You cant convert DBNull to a date which is the point of the error message,

Comment: Question is not duplicated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing sdr("date1") by

```
 If(sdr("date1") is nothing,nothing,sdr("date1"))
```

Or

```
If(IsDbNull(sdr("date1")),nothing,sdr("date1"))
```

Comment: Think about what you've just done :). You've basically just said if the date is nothing pass nothing which is the same as passing `sdr("date1")`.

Comment: Edited my code :)

Comment: Dim test As Date
                        test = If(IsDBNull(sdr("date1")), "", sdr("date1"))

just moves the problem so I now can't assign "" to a Date...  doesn't resolve the issue...

Sorry for reposts - trying to get used to this "forum"...

Comment: Try replacing "" with Nothing

Comment: @Jinx88909 My answer was true before editing !! :)

Comment: Ok - I've gotten past hurdle # (lost count).  Had to use SEVERAL instances of this construct type (some with Nothing, some with "", some with 0, etc.), since many fields in the DB are NULL (not just Date, etc. - that was just the first one I hit).  

And I did find the link to the "duplicate" (took a bit getting used to the format of the page) - however, what was supposed to be a duplicate with answer was NOT.  Later comments by the OP showed they still had original problem, even with the item marked as answered.  And they were running into timeout issues, not exactly what I was.

Comment: @H.Fadlallah your first example is the checking of nothing and if true passing nothing which is the same. The second example could be the one though.

Comment: You're right .... :)